# How to understand the proof of Theorem 2.7.1 in the Book **Topics in Functional Analysis and Applications by S. Kesavan**?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have been trying to read Theorem 2.7.1 in the Book **Topics in Functional Analysis and Applications by S. Kesavan. New Age International (formerly Wiley-Eastern), 1989**.  However, I am struggling to fill in some gaps in the proof.  For instance:

(a) why do we have $$|v(x',0)|^2 = -\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}(|v(x',x_n)|^2)dx_n?$$
Is it from the definitions of $L^p$ norms? Is it from the definition of functions in $C^\infty_0$?

(b) Why $$-\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}(|v(x',x_n)|^2)dx_n=-2\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial x_N}(x',x_N)v(x',x_N) dx_N?$$  I thought this step was due to integration by parts.  But still it does not come out clearly.

(c) Which inequality related to integration yields this step? $$-2\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial x_N}(x',x_N)v(x',x_N) dx_N\leq \int_0^\infty \left(\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial x_N}(x',x_N)\right|^2+ \left|v(x',x_N)\right|^2\right) dx_N.$$

I am a beginner in PDE, someone help me.

Comment: (a) Fundamental theorem of calculus, (b) product rule, (c) $2ab \le a^2 +b^2$.

Comment: Thank you please!